# How to properly use JQuery Datatable sAjaxSource with Apex providing JSON source

Tags: apex, jquery, json, datatable

I'm trying to use sAjaxSource with server side processing from Apex class which will provide JSON as source.
First I was trying simple example, which won't work and won't output any error (not in Salesforce and not in JS console), I'm just getting empty JQuery DataTable.

Visualforce page:

```
<apex:page controller="vfDBTestController">

    <apex:includeScript value="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js" />
    <apex:stylesheet value="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css"/>
    <apex:includeScript value="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.min.js" />

    <apex:includeScript value="{!URLFOR($Resource.DataTables_1_9_4, 'DataTables-1.9.4/media/js/jquery.dataTables.js')}"/>
    <apex:stylesheet value="{!URLFOR($Resource.DataTables_1_9_4, 'DataTables-1.9.4/media/css/jquery.dataTables_themeroller.css')}" />  

    <script type="text/javascript">
        var j$ = jQuery.noConflict();
        j$(document).ready( function () 
        {
            j$('#tblid').dataTable(
            {
                "bProcessing"   : true,
                "sAjaxSource"   : {!JSONDataSource}
            } );
        } );
    </script>

    <apex:form >

        <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="display" id="tblid">
            <thead>
                <th>cell1</th>
                <th>cell2</th>
            </thead>
            <tbody>

            </tbody>
        </table>

    </apex:form>

</apex:page>
```

Apex:

```
public with sharing class vfDBTestController 
{     
    public vfDBTestController(){}

    public String getJSONDataSource()
    {
        List<Account> lstAaData = [SELECT Id, Name FROM Account];

        // Create a JSONGenerator object.
        // Pass true to the constructor for pretty print formatting.
        JSONGenerator gen = JSON.createGenerator(true);

        // Write data to the JSON string.
        gen.writeStartObject();
        gen.writeFieldName('aaData');
        gen.writeStartArray();

        for (Account acc : lstAaData)
        {
            gen.writeStartObject();
            gen.writeStringField('cell1', acc.Name);
            gen.writeStringField('cell2', acc.Id);
            gen.writeEndObject();
        }
        gen.writeEndArray();
        gen.writeEndObject();

        String JSONString = gen.getAsString();
        system.debug('JSONString: ' + JSONString);
        return JSONString;
    }

}
```

JSON output from system debug:

```
{"aaData":[{"cell1" : "GenePoint","cell2" : "001b000000MTqJJAA1"},{"cell1" : "United Oil & Gas, UK","cell2" : "001b000000MTqJKAA1"},{"cell1" : "United Oil & Gas, Singapore","cell2" : "001b000000MTqJLAA1"}]}
```

Comment: You might also be able to set it dynamically:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6967673/how-to-reload-dataset-in-jquery-datatable-plugin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found an answer with help from [here](http://www.tgerm.com/2010/02/visualforce-salesforce-jquery-ajax-how.html).
I will give a small example, which shows how to use this technique related to JQuery DataTable.

Note: this is only small example that shows how one can communicate with JQuery DataTable and Apex, to get a good grasp on the matter. Hope it will help more people who trying this.

Ajax Response VF page:

```
<apex:page controller="AjaxRespController"  action="{!retrieveData}"
    contentType="application/x-JavaScript; charset=utf-8" showHeader="false" standardStylesheets="false" sidebar="false">
{!JSONString}
</apex:page>
```

AjaxRespController:

```
public class AjaxRespController 
{
    public String JSONString {get;set;}

    public AjaxRespController() {}

    /** invoked on an Ajax request */   
    public void retrieveData() 
    {
        // We need those parameters to work with JQuery DataTable.
        Map<String, String> params = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters();
        for (String key : params.keySet())
        {
            system.debug('Key: ' + key + ', Value: ' + params.get(key));
        }
        List<Account> lstAaData = [SELECT Id, Name FROM Account LIMIT 10];

        // Create a JSONGenerator object.
        // Pass true to the constructor for pretty print formatting.
        JSONGenerator gen = JSON.createGenerator(true);

        // Write data to the JSON string.
        gen.writeStartObject();
        gen.writeNumberField('sEcho', Integer.valueOf(params.get('sEcho')));
        gen.writeNumberField('iTotalRecords', 14);
        gen.writeNumberField('iTotalDisplayRecords', 14);
        gen.writeFieldName('aaData');       
        gen.writeStartArray();
        for (Account acc : lstAaData)
        {       
            gen.writeStartArray();
            gen.writeString(acc.Name);
            gen.writeString(acc.Id);
            gen.writeEndArray();

        }

        gen.writeEndArray();
        gen.writeEndObject();

        JSONString = gen.getAsString();     
    }

}
```

VF client page:

```
<apex:page>
    <apex:includeScript value="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js" />
    <apex:stylesheet value="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css"/>
    <apex:includeScript value="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.min.js" />

    <apex:includeScript value="{!URLFOR($Resource.DataTables_1_9_4, 'DataTables-1.9.4/media/js/jquery.dataTables.js')}"/>
    <apex:stylesheet value="{!URLFOR($Resource.DataTables_1_9_4, 'DataTables-1.9.4/media/css/jquery.dataTables_themeroller.css')}" />  

    <script type="text/javascript">

        var j$ = jQuery.noConflict();
        j$(document).ready( function () 
        {           
            j$('#tblid').dataTable(
            {
                "bProcessing"   : true,
                "bServerSide"   : true,
                "sAjaxSource"   : '{!$Page.AjaxResponder}?core.apexpages.devmode.url=1'
            } );
        } );

    </script>

    <apex:form >
        <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="display" id="tblid">
            <thead>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Id</th>
            </thead>
            <tbody>

            </tbody>
        </table>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Comment: Glad to see you've found a solution. Fyi, I've seen comments from Salesforce about query string parameters (the "core.apexpages.devmode.url" in your case) not being part of their API and so subject to change. But I question if they can remove/change such parameters if many people are using them. (I also did notice that DataTables supports a fnServerData property that in theory would allow the JavaScript generated by an "@RemoteAction" to be called.)

Comment: Thank you for all your help. I also read about fnServerData and was thinking about using "@RemoteAction" with it, but I still need to use a URL in the sAjaxSource which is the source given to the fnServerData, so as I see it am still back to the original problem I had.

Comment: Yeah I tried fnServerData for a few minutes too and couldn't get it to work. I might give it another go soon - seems like it ought to be possible.

Comment: Fyi - did get the fnServerData thing to work - see http://force201.wordpress.com/2014/03/15/connecting-datatables-to-json-generated-by-apex/.

Answer (score 2):

Based on [DataTables AJAX source example](http://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/ajax.html), `sAjaxSource` should be a URL that returns the JSON not a literal copy of the JSON. I suggest you dig into the DataTables documentation further to figure out the right data loading mode as you experiment.

If you did want to emit JSON into the generated page, you would have to add quotes like this '{!JSONDataSource}'; view the source of the generated page to make sure it looks right. I also wouldn't expect things like "aaData" to be in your JSON.

I've used DataTables and found it to be excellent and to work well in Salesforce.

**PS**

I've posted some sample code that uses `sAjaxSource` here http://force201.wordpress.com/2014/03/15/connecting-datatables-to-json-generated-by-apex/.

Comment: Thank for your info. The quotes don't work (Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL), and I'm familiar with my browser dev tools, as I was mentioned I don't see any error in the javascript debug console (prior to the change you suggested). I do understand from what you said that I need to write a web service which will provide the JSON, I'll try it and get back here to update.

Comment: I should have suggested single quotes as double quotes are use in the JSON - the JSON needs to be interpreted by JavaScript as a single string. I've edited the answer to reflect this. Missed your comment about the JS console too.

Comment: It gave me the same error as double quotes. I think your suggestion about providing the source as URL is the solution, so I'm building a web service with apex code that will provide the JSON, and I'll get back here to update.

Comment: Update: When using apex Rest Service - `"sAjaxSource" : "https://eu2.salesforce.com/services/apexrest/test/test_rest_api"`, I have a probelm described here [link](https://github.com/developerforce/Force.com-JavaScript-REST-Toolkit/), but that not helping me getting a URL with JSON output within my ORG, to use server-side processing, any more suggestions will be most helpful.

Comment: I'm unclear what your problem is exactly; consuming JSON generated in the same server by an @RestResource that your page comes from requires no special mechanism and you are automatically authenticated. Perhaps you should post a separate question detailing the specific problem including the current code and any error reported? (You can link to this question as background info.)

Comment: The question stands, I want to use jquery datatable server side processing, with Apex. Since, as you said sAjaxSource should be a URL that returns the JSON, I understands that I need to provide a URL, so I'm trying to do it with a Apex REST service. Similar to this example: [link](http://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/server_side.html), just with apex and not PHP.

Comment: Fair enough. You mentioned a problem in your previous "Update: When using apex Rest Service" comment and I don't understand what your problem is so can't comment further. Good luck.

Comment: I'll quote the problem from [here](https://github.com/developerforce/Force.com-JavaScript-REST-Toolkit/): _Due to the same origin policy, JavaScript running in Visualforce pages may not use XmlHttpRequest to directly invoke the REST API, since Visualforce pages have hostnames of the form abc.na1.visual.force.com, and the REST API endpoints are of the form na1.salesforce.com._ Hope that gives more information, note that the solution he provides not good for getting URL as it is to the sAjaxSource.

Comment: My fault. I'm blind to this problem because I've only used "@RestResource: with an AngularJs client served from a Site where the domain is the same. "@RemoteAction" emits a JavaScript function but I can't see an obvious way that DataTable can call it. Hopefully someone else can help you solve this problem...